# Python find pairs when from subset (pair numbers are changing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset:

```
d1 = {'Indiv1':['Subject1','Subject2','Subject1','Subject1','Subject2','Subject1','Subject1','Subject2'],
'Indiv2': ['Subject4','Subject3','Subject2','Subject4','Subject4','Subject2','Subject3','Subject3'],
'Event':['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3'],
'Category':['1','2','1','1','1','2','2','2'],
'Variable1':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
'Variable2':['12','11','10','9','8','7','6','5'],
'Variable3': ['-4','-3','-2','-1','0','1','2','3']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)  
d1=d1[['Indiv1','Indiv2','Event','Category','Variable1','Variable2','Variable3']]
d1
```

Which gives the following (In my dataset this particular file has **over 2 million rows**):

d1=

[image]

I have a second smaller dataset **(about 1500 rows)** in the following format:

```
d2 = {'Indiv1': ['Subject1','Subject3','Subject1','Subject4','Subject2','Subject1','Subject1','Subject2'],
'Indiv2': ['Subject4','Subject2','Subject6','Subject1','Subject1','Subject8','Subject9','Subject113'],
'Event':['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3'],
'Category':['1','2','1','1','1','2','2','2']}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
d2=d2[['Indiv1','Indiv2','Event','Category']]
d2
```

which looks like the following:

d2=

[image]

what I need to do is to look up the pairs of subjects in each event in each category from the second file (d2). If the pair exixts in both d1 and d2 for the given event id and category, then assign 1 to the row in df1. Otherwise assign 0.

[image]

Note that in row 2 of df2, the order of the two individuals are flipped. Instead of Subject 2 and Subject 3 as in d1, in d2 we have Subject 3 and Subject 2. However, in my case I want to treat both as the same. In this case, I want to assign a value of 1 to these cases.

[image]

Finally there are pairs in d1 which are not in d2 (for each event, for each category). For example, for event 3, there is no pair with Subject1 and Subject 2 in df2 (although this exists in df1). In such a case, assign a value =0 under the column present. The final output will look like this:

[image]

I am especially very perplexed with how to do it. Especially in the case, when groupings may change (Subject1 and Subject 2) vs (Subject2 and Subject 1).

Any help will be appreciated. Ty in advance.

Please let me know if I amam unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a key by using indiv1 and indiv2 with `np.sort`, then using `isin`(drop it by using `d1.drop('key',1 inplace=True)`)

```
d2['key']=np.sort(d2.iloc[:,:2],axis=1).sum(1)+d2.Event.astype(str)
d1['key']=np.sort(d1.iloc[:,:2],axis=1).sum(1)+d1.Event.astype(str)
d1['persent']=d1.key.isin(d2.key).astype(int)
d1
Out[39]: 
     Indiv1    Indiv2 Event Category Variable1 Variable2 Variable3  \
0  Subject1  Subject4     1        1         1        12        -4   
1  Subject2  Subject3     1        2         2        11        -3   
2  Subject1  Subject2     2        1         3        10        -2   
3  Subject1  Subject4     2        1         4         9        -1   
4  Subject2  Subject4     2        1         5         8         0   
5  Subject1  Subject2     3        2         6         7         1   
6  Subject1  Subject3     3        2         7         6         2   
7  Subject2  Subject3     3        2         8         5         3   
                 key  persent  
0  Subject1Subject41        1  
1  Subject2Subject31        1  
2  Subject1Subject22        1  
3  Subject1Subject42        1  
4  Subject2Subject42        0  
5  Subject1Subject23        0  
6  Subject1Subject33        0  
7  Subject2Subject33        0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Wen. I see a couple of ones (row 5 and 7) when the value of present should be zero. Note that for event 3 in category 2, we do not observe Subject1 and Subject2. How do I limit the lookup by the event and category? In its current state, I think the lookup is on the entire dataset. I want to see if for event 1 in category 1, the pair Subject 1 and Subject 4 exists. Please let me know if my question is a little confusing. I could edit my original question. Thanks.

Comment: @Prometheus got u, one sec

Comment: @Prometheus check the update , also , I create the new key here is to speed up the process, usually we can using `groupby`, but since your d1 is big , I think create a new key is more efficient